# Dimerization of Immunoglobulin G

Tags: biochemistry, immunology, antibody

I would like to know the specific determinants for formation of IgG dimers. My understanding is the stem of the antibody is a homodimer of two heavy chains, covalently bonded through two disulfide bridges called the hinge region. Is there any association between the constant region? My reading would suggest no but I have not found a specific reference as such.

Comment: Do you mean disulfides linking constant regions?

Comment: No, of course each immunoglubulin-like domain has an intramolecular disulfide (stabilizing the beta sandwich conformation). I mean between two heavy chain molecules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For human IgG1 and 4, the only inter-heavy chain disulfide bonds are the two in the hinge region. IgG2 has 4 disulfides in the hinge, and IgG3 has 11:

[image]

There are intra-heavy chain disulfides in the Fc region, and of course there are non-covalent bonds between the two heavy chains (as well as the light chains) to maintain structure, but aside from the hinge region the only other inter-chain disulfides are between heavy and light.

[Here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22327427) is an interesting review of classical (determined in the 1960s) and non-classical (more recently discovered) disulfide bond formation and structure in human IgGs.

Comment: What's the nature of the hydrogen bonds/non-covalent bonding between two heavy chains? Are they naturally aggregated in the cell?

Comment: What do you mean by nature? This bonds are formed in the cell, yes, during the assembly of the antibody.